# ListFragment exception -> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm trying to create a ListFragment with different information but doesn't work and i don't know why.
This is my ListFragment class

```
public class Countries extends ListFragment{

       private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayCountryAdapter;
       private Countries.OnFragmentInteractionListener mCallback;

       public Countries(){
           //Public Constructor
       }

       @Override
       public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
       }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        CountryController countryController = new CountryController();
        String[] countries = countryController.getCountries();
        if(countries != null) {

            arrayCountryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);
            setListAdapter(arrayCountryAdapter);
        }
        else{
            //If the list are null
            setEmptyText("Server Error, try again later");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        //Notify the parent Activity of selected item
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click on the Element", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);
        //Set the item as checked
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallback = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallback = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);

    }
}
```

This the layout for the fragment

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.twopaneapplication.Fragments.Countries">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewCountries"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty_list"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Activity associated with the previous ListFragment

```
public class CountryActivity extends Activity implements Countries.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_country);
    }

    public void onArticleSelected(int position){
        //Make an Intent for call the other activity
    }
}
```

And their layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/countries"
        android:name="com.example.twopaneapplication.Fragments.Countries"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_countries"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The ListFragment i commented is called from another ListFragment when clicked on some element with an intent

```
MainActivity.java
   ...
   public void onArticleSelected(int position){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CountryActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
   }
```

And this is the stacktrace for the exception

```
12-24 14:30:55.436      836-836/com.example.twopaneapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.twopaneapplication/com.example.twopaneapplication.Activities.CountryActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at com.example.twopaneapplication.Activities.CountryActivity.onCreate(CountryActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.twopaneapplication.Controllers.CountryController.getCountries(CountryController.java:42)
            at com.example.twopaneapplication.Fragments.Countries.onCreate(Countries.java:35)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:796)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1112)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4664)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at com.example.twopaneapplication.Activities.CountryActivity.onCreate(CountryActivity.java:16)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Hope someone could help me, i'm stuck on this like an entire day. 
Thanks!

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.twopaneapplication.Controllers.CountryController.getCountries(CountryController.java:42)`

Comment: Sounds like your getCountries method on line 42 in CountryController.java is evaluating to null.

Comment: You are right! i completely forgot a foreach bucle! Thanks to both!